# Annotating a PHP variable for two different types

Tags: php, annotations

**Background**

Given I have a `gimme()` that can return either an instance of `ClassA` or an instance of `ClassB`, I want to annotate the variable that recieves it.

```
$gotIt = gimme();
```

**Question**

Now I want to annotate this variable, but since it can be either `ClassA` OR `ClassB`, can I cover both?

In pseudo, this is what I want

```
/** @var (ClassA OR ClassB) $gotIt */
$gotIt = gimme();
```

Comment: `@var ClassA|ClassB`

Comment: @MarkBaker - Yup, that did the trick. I now get auto-completions. Thanks! (Make sure to write it as an answer if you want the points.)

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Baker commented, `/** @var ClassA|ClassB $gotIt */` properly told the IDE that the variable could be an instance of one of these two classes.

The IDE can then provide things like auto completion, jump to source, or other functionality instead of marking warnings where it cannot find, for example `$gotIt->someFunction()`.